# Django Celery FFMPEG: convert video files

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, celery

I'm trying to convert video files using FFMPEG via Celery tasks. The generated command to be executed looks like

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/flv -ar 22050 -ab 96k -r 24 -b 600k -f flv path/to/flv/transcoded/flv_movie.flv
```

and when I call the task `TranscodeVideoTask.delay(src=filepath, dst=destination_path)` 
I get `flv_movie.flv` file but its size is only about `200Kb` and debug output

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x10205a200] Reference 3 >= 3
[h264 @ 0x10205a200] error while decoding MB 7 5, bytestream (690)
[h264 @ 0x10205a200] concealing 762 DC, 762 AC, 762 MV errors
frame=   40 fps=  0 q=2.0 Lsize=     136kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate= 668.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=9    
video:114kB audio:20kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.814991%
```

TranscodeVideoTask source

```
@task(name="transcode.media")
def TranscodeVideoTask(src, dst):
    command = commands.get("flv") % {"src": src, "dst": dst}
    os.system(src, dst)
    filename = os.path.join(dst, "flv_movie.flv")
    YamdiInjector.yamdi(filename, dst)
```

When the same command executed manually in the console it works just fine.

`UPDATE`
So far I've composed the following ffmpeg instructions in my bash file and it converts almost every avi file I tested already

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=$1
OUTPUT=$2/flv_movie.flv

echo "Input file: ${INPUT}"
echo "Output file: ${OUTPUT}"
echo `ffmpeg -y -i $INPUT -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -sameq -f flv $OUTPUT`
```

What may cause this strange problem?

Sultan

Comment: Can you add to post source of `TranscodeVideoTask`? And maybe sample of video file.

Comment: Temporarily I've solved this problem using shell script which contains FFMPEG instructions and is actually called by Celery with `src` and `dst` parameters

Comment: TranscodeVideoTask's source looks very strange, because you create `command` variable, but then try execute `src, dst` in os.system: `os.system(src, dst)`